# protobuf with grpc for Go in split packages

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc, protoc, grpc-go

I'm trying to make my Go project using hexagonal architecture as described [here](https://medium.com/@matiasvarela/hexagonal-architecture-in-go-cfd4e436faa3).
In my project I'm using a gRPC communication generated with `protoc` from `.proto` file.

The directories structure:

```
|- grpc.proto
|-internal
  |-core
    |-domain
  |-services
    |- grpcprotocol
```

And my **grpc.proto** file has go_package option that points to a specific directory in my Go project

```
syntax = "proto3";
option go_package = "github.com/myuser/myrepo/internal/core/services/grpcprotocol";
...
```

Using `protoc --go_out=internal/core/domain --go_opt=paths=source_relative --go-grpc_out=internal/core/services/grpcprotocol --go-grpc_opt=paths=source_relative ports.proto` I'm able to generate both **grpc.pb.go** file in *internal/core/domain* directory and **grpc_grpc.pb.go** file inside *internal/core/services/grpcprotocol* directory.

However, **grpc.pb.go** has a go package named `grpcprotocol` while it should have a package named `domain` (I also use other types defined there in separate Go files).
Also **grpc_grpc.pb.go** file has code that uses types defined in **grpc.pb.go** without imports (it treats it as if it was defined in the same package).

Is it possible to split those two files into separate Go packages and enforce code that's in **grpc_grpc.pb.go** to import types from domain directory instead of treating them as defined in the same package?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, one proto file represents a single `package`'s (and thus a single language-specific "package" or equivalent too). Because the (gRPC) services are referencing messages in the same package, there's no way to have `protoc` understand how to split these. You can achieve this by namespacing your messages and services in separate packages (`package your_messages`, `package your_services`), `import`'ing the messages into the services proto and then generating the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best solution here is too separate the code that you want in `grpcprotocol` and the one you want into `domain`, into separate files. Such as:

#### domain.proto

```proto
syntax = "proto3";
package domain;
option go_package = "github.com/myuser/myrepo/internal/core/domain";

//...
```

#### grpc.proto

```proto
syntax = "proto3";
package grpcprotocol;
option go_package = "github.com/myuser/myrepo/internal/core/services/grpcprotocol";

//...
```

Then you could import your `domain.proto` in your `grpc.proto`, by simply writing `import "domain.proto";`, provide a `--proto_path` if `domain.proto` and `grpc.proto` are not in the same directory. And finally to reference an object from `domain.proto` in `grpc.proto` you can write:

```
domain.AnObject
```

After that you can take advantage of the `--go_opt=module` and `--go-grpc_opt=module`, to strip the module name in `go_package` and generate the code at the right place. Like:

```
protoc --go_out=. --go_opt=module=github.com/myuser/myrepo --go-grpc_out=. --go-grpc_opt=module=github.com/myuser/myrepo *.proto
```

What this will do is that, it will remove `github.com/myuser/myrepo` from each `go_package` and basically start from the root of your module. That's why you can do a `--go_out=.` and `--go-grpc_out=.`.

Hope that helps, let me know how I can further improve my answer.

### Notes

- Protobuf package and `go_package` are not the same. The former is only used for protobuf in order to give context and it extends the qualified name. The `go_package` is used during go code generation.
- The `package` in the proto file is optional, it makes things more clear and nobody can misuse you proto file without specifying the fully qualified  name (little bit safer, if named properly).

Comment: Thanks a lot! :) It solved my problem